# Where are Websphere AS transaction manager logs?

Tags: jakarta-ee, logging, transactions, websphere, jta

Does Websphere Application Server (7.0, preferably) have a log for transaction manager? I'd like to see how and when transactions are started for my application's threads, whether and when they commit or rollback, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to set logging for the package `com.ibm.wsspi.uow` (maybe `com.ibm.websphere.uow` and `com.ibm.websphere.jtaextensions` too) to `FINEST` (somewhere in your WebSphere administrative console). This should give you plenty information about what's going on.

Maybe the Spring Framework documentation about [it's WebSphere-specific PlatformTransactionManager](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/jta/WebSphereUowTransactionManager.html) gives helpful background infos (packages, classes, jndi, etc.) too.