# Transaction demarcation/transaction borders in Spring JMS

Tags: java, spring, transactions, jms, jta

I have a chain of 3 Spring JMS listeners *A*, *B* and *C* implemented on `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` (DMLC). All DMLCs are deployed in one Java EE application.

*A* and *C*:

- have a transaction manager injected (the same one),
- they both **receive** and **send** messages in transacted sessions,
- the same ConnectionFactory is injected in their DMLC (for receiving) and used for sending.

*B*:

- has no transaction manager,
- sends transactionless messages (`Connection.createSession(false, AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)`),
- has a different, non-XA ConnectionFactory

**Question:** are transaction borders as illustrated below, and transactions 1 and 2 are separate (ML = message listener)?

```
         |   transaction 1 |    ?   | no transaction |    ?   | transaction 2 |
 (broker) --> [ML A]   -->  (broker)  --> [ML B]  --> (broker) --> [ML C]     |
```

Or maybe transaction 1 and 2 are one, and the fact that the "ML B" is non-transactional has no effect on continuity?

**Additional question:** what happens to the active transaction in the places marked "?", when the message is in the broker?

I don't know how to access [transaction manager logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482122/where-are-websphere-as-transaction-manager-logs), so I cannot really verify that.